# How can i "wget" the content of this site

Tags: wget

If I run:

```
wget 'http://beforeitsnews.com/stories/in/0000000000000013' -O -
```

I can't see the news...why? How can i `wget` or `curl` this site, so that i can see the news on it? I can't even browse it with `elinks` :(

Comment: ...if it had no JS, you could use `$ lynx -dump yoursite.com` (a killer cmd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That site requires JavaScript to be enabled. None of the tools you mention can interpret JavaScript.

Comment: and how could i download the sites content via command line? :\

Comment: You'd try to find a tool that can display a page like a GUI browser. I don't know of one. Try to see if one of them (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, ...) has a command line switch like "-dump". Try to see if there is a program that can mechanize a GUI browser.

Comment: elinks supports JavaScript. Rather, ECMAScript.

Answer (score 1):

[Links2](http://links.twibright.com/) with a trigger of -g should take care of that JavaScript problem.

You'll might need some tweaking to do to meet your monitor or terminal for that there is always a man page.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might like [Fake.app](http://fakeapp.com/), but I have no idea to what extent it offers saving/output. Perhaps with Fake and Automator you could load the page, save a snapshot, move to the next page number?